# Import entries to Umbraco Contour

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco-contour

Is there a way (the best would be an Excel importer) to import entries to an Umbraco Contour form?

Comment: What is the reason for wanting this for Contour? Why not straight into Umbraco? I know there is a commercial package called CMSImport, which supports Excel

Comment: I know the CMSImport and its already in use but with this one I can't import to contour. And I need an importer for contour. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no way to import records to Contour out of the box I'm afraid. You'd have to use the Contour APIs and do it yourself, although there will be some complexities around items that have lists, like dropdown lists or multiple checkboxes.